# 数値を下一桁の位だけ操作する方法

Tags: python

a = 43.8664　→ a = 43.8665
b = 45.058333333 → b = 45.058333334

上記のように桁が異なっていても下一桁の位の数値のみを操作する方法はありませんか？
小数点以下の桁数を文字列で取得して下一桁だけ+1する手法は考えつきましたが，
ライブラリ等で可能に出来るものがありましたらご教授いただけませんでしょうか．

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　今回行いたいことの詳細を伺いたいです。(1) ぴったり整数のときはどう動作しますか？ たとえば `a = 1.0` のときは `1.1` にするのでしょうか。 (2) ぴったり `0` のときはどう動作して欲しいですか？

Comment: （Pythonに限らず大抵）43.8664などは正確に表せないので、まず「下一桁の位」とはどこを指すのかを定義する必要があります。

Comment: (1)ぴったり整数の場合でも表示されている最小位の数値を操作できるような形にしたいです．(2)ピッタリ0の場合は基本的に無いものとして考えていただきたいです．

Comment: [浮動小数点演算、その問題と制限](https://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)に説明されていますが、Pythonが浮動小数点数を表示（文字列への変換）する際は、適当に見やすいようにまるめています。
ですから、この表示上の「最小位」は数値計算を行なう際にはあまり意味がありません。
こういった事情を承知の上で数値計算ではなく、何らかの視覚的な表現を目的として操作する場合は、最初から文字列として保持し、文字列処理で行なうのがよいかも知れません。
いずれにせよ、この場合は、質問者さんが行なおうとしている操作の最終的な目的を。簡単で結構ですので質問に含めた方が回答が得られやすいかと思います。

Comment: 0.1 なんてのも正確には表せないと思ったが違いますか? (浮動小数点の基本的問題)  mjyさんの書かれたように、その目的はなんでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

小数点数は数値として与えられるのではなく10進数表記の**文字列**として与えられ、文字列で表現された精度で一つだけプラスし、文字列として返すと言うことで良いでしょうか？それであれば、[decimal](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/decimal.html)が使えると思います。下記のような感じにです。

```
from decimal import Decimal, Context

def last_up(num_s):
    num = Decimal(num_s)
    return str(num.next_plus(Context(len(num.as_tuple().digits))))

print(last_up('43.8664')) # => 43.8665
print(last_up('45.058333333')) # => 45.058333334
print(last_up('42.320000')) # => 42.320001
```